# SUM each row with corresponding row of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update the values of a select number of rows from one column to each be incremented by a certain value taken from another column from another table but I keep hitting this wall : 'single-row subquery returns more than one row'.

Essentially what this is all about is deleting a hypothetical shopping cart (each row in the shopping cart corresponds to a certain item and a desired quantity of that item) but before doing that I must first make sure that all the item quantities from the cart are returned to the product relation which keeps track of all available items and the quantity of those items currently on supply.

`UPDATE Product SET supply = (...)`  - subquery returning a single column list of all quantites to be added back to the respective product supplies, ordered by the product_id - even though it's not included in the select statement

`WHERE product_id IN (...)` - same query as the last one but returns the product ids of all the corresponding shopping cart items rather than their quantities, again ordered by product_id

All looks fine but ORACLE's not having it. Perhaps this can be looped somehow? If not I'll have to resort to doing it in the app layer (PHP)

Product relation:

| product_id | Supply | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | ... |
| 2 | 20 | ... |
| 3 | 10 | ... |

Basket relation:

| product_id | quantity | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ... |
| 2 | 4 | ... |

Upon the deletion of the cart I would like the two quantities from the cart table to be added back to their corresponding rows in the supply column in the product relation

This:

| product_id | Supply | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | ... |
| 2 | 20 | ... |
| 3 | 10 | ... |

Turns into this:

| product_id | Supply | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **13** | ... |
| 2 | **24** | ... |
| 3 | 10 | ... |

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @Sergey absolutely, just gimme a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use corelated subquery as follows:

```
Update product p
Set p.supply = p.supply + coalesce(select quantity from basket b
      Where b.product_id = p.product_id), 0)
```

It is considered good to use `exists` to reduce the redo logs as follows:

```
Update product p
Set p.supply = p.supply + (select quantity from basket b
      Where b.product_id = p.product_id)
 WHERE EXISTS 
       (Select 1 from basket b
      Where b.product_id = p.product_id)
```

Please note that we have removed the `coalesce` in this query as it is not required if we use `exists`.

Comment: no way that actually worked ! I've personally never used coalesce so it didn't occur to me to use it here.. wow thank you

Comment: yep, ```exists``` works even better! doesn't seem very intuitive at first though..